# EditText Multiline - After hide of Keyboard its Singleline

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a **EditText** and if I type some text it will expand to the second line if the Text is too long.

So far so good.

But if I **hide the keyboard** the EditText converts to a **SingeLine** and without scrolling behaviour.

What's going on here?

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:lines="2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/background"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        />
```

**On typing with keyboard open:**

[image]

**After keyboard hide:**

[image]

Full XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:background="@color/app_color">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_misc_light_24dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/background"
        />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</merge>
```

Comment: Can you show a full ScreenShoot?.... I can't see if the device cuts the rest of the sentence.... Is the EditText ending with this "a" cutted?

Comment: Yes this is a full screenshot. This is the end of the screen. I have no padding added at this time. But it does not cut it. If I tap beofere the a and hit enter on the keyboard it moves it to the next line and I see the full text again...

Comment: Try to change the `height` and `width` to this `android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Comment: layout_height is already wrap_content. And why should I set the width to "fill parent" ? This is deprecated since API 8 --> fill_parent (deprecated and renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher)

Comment: Okay, hold on... let me test it on a demo project...

Comment: Hm... I'm testing it and it doesn't convert to SingleLine... it only creates a `ScrollView` to see the full code typed....

Comment: Can you paste the code for the rest of your xml? Because I did not face this problem as you can see [here](http://s6.postimg.org/x7rf8kujl/device_2015_07_26_113338.png).

Comment: There must be somthing with the complete layout because it has always worked before. I have redesigned it to a TableLayout and now I have this strange behaviour. Code added above.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem.
In the main XML where the merge happens I have added by mistake an +id who was already there in another include layout with merge.

I removed that and now it works as it should.
Really strange that I get no error about the doubled +id's!

**Old code:**

```
        <!-- Note -->
        <include layout="@layout/inc_reminder_note" android:id="+id/areaDate"/>

        <!-- Date and Time -->
        <include layout="@layout/inc_reminder_date_time"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
```

**New code:**

```
         <!-- Note -->
        <include layout="@layout/inc_reminder_note" />

        <!-- Date and Time -->
        <include layout="@layout/inc_reminder_date_time"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
```

The layout "**inc_reminder_date_time**" had also as id "**areaDate**".